# Google API Authorisation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-client

Hi I hope someone can help with this because it's driving me crazy right now.

I am trying to replicate this Google API authorisation example https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/source/browse/samples/authSample.html on my own web server http://james-gilmore.co.uk/test.html

I have duplicated the code but replaced the clientID and API key with the keys set up in the google api console and I have turned the Google+ api service on in the 'Services' section.

I have the following set up under 'Client ID for web applications'

Redirect URIs: http://james-gilmore.co.uk/oauth2callback
JavaScript origins: http://james-gilmore.co.uk

And I also have the following set up under 'Simple API Access'

Referers: *.james-gilmore.co.uk/*.

When I run the http://james-gilmore.co.uk/test.html script I can authorise my access but I can see a JS error generated in the console:

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined'

Does anyone know what I could be doing incorrectly? I think it may have  something to do with the setup of my client ID's and allowed Referers because when I run the following example https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=plus it works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth authentication appears to be working, but I see an error `Access Not Configured` being returned from an AJAX call.

Set up your referers as `james-gilmore.co.uk/*` (with the trailing wildcard, so that it will allow anything *starting with* your domain name).

Comment: Awesome! I can't believe thats all it was. Thanks for your help it's much appreciated!